# Errors belonging to child of UserControl are associated with UserControl in stead of the child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I've created a UserControl that is designed for re-use and must be totally independent. It has dependency properties, doesn't set its DataContext to anything, and in its template it only binds to its own dependency propeties.

This is an example situation:

The control is used for entering an address. It contains a few fields (City, street, PO box, etc.).
The control has dependency properties like `CityProperty`, `StreetProperty`, ...
Each field has a binding to the corresponding dependency property. So the *street* `TextBox` `Text` has a binding with `StreetProperty` DP of the UserControl.
Because there's no datacontext set from within the control explicitly, it'll always inherit the datacontext from its parent.

When using my control by embedding it in another control (view), I use its dependency properties to define a binding with the ViewModel (datacontext) of the view it is placed in.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="someView" DataContext=" ... a viewmodel ... "> <!-- Some view that uses my Address control -->

<TextBlock>Enter an address</TextBlock> <!-- Just some parts of the view -->

<myControls:AddressControl 
    City="{Binding ShippingCity"
    Street="{Binding ShippingStreet}"
    ...
/>

</StackPanel>
```

My control's dependency properties are bound to ViewModel properties of the view the control is placed in.
The ViewModel implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

When there are validation errors, the errors should be 'attached' to the corresponding `TextBox`es in the UserControl. A TextBox in the usercontrol should be in error state and change its appearance to its error template.

But what actually happens, is that the UserControl detects there's one or more errors associated with a binding to its dependency property. The framework interprets the control as one thing that has 'some' error. A red border around the entire UserControl is displayed (default behavior).

I want to display the errors to the corresponding field in the UserControl. But I don't know how to do this.
How to handle the validation errors on bindings to dependency properties of a UserControl so, that the validation error can be forwarded to the correct child control in that UserControl. The only association between validation errors from the ViewModel to the right child control in the UserControl, is the imaginary 'route' via the dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a `UserControl` class called an `AddressControl` that can be reused without dependence on external objects. And any change from outside control to inside control.

***AddressControl.cs***

```
public partial class AddressControl : UserControl, IDataErrorInfo
{
   public string City
   {
      get { return (string)GetValue(CityProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CityProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for City.  This enables styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty CityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("City", typeof(string), typeof(AddressControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCityChanged)));

   private static void OnCityChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   {
      AddressControl ac = new AddressControl();
      ac.ChangeCityText();
   }
   public void ChangeCityText()
   {
      txtCity.Text = City;
   }

   public string Street
   {
      get { return (string)GetValue(StreetProperty); }
      set { SetValue(StreetProperty, value); }
   }

   // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Street.  This enables styling, binding, etc...
   public static readonly DependencyProperty StreetProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("Street", typeof(string), typeof(AddressControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStreetChanged)));

   private static void OnStreetChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   {
      AddressControl ac = new AddressControl();
      ac.ChangeStreetText();
   }
   public void ChangeStreetText()
   {
      txtStreet.Text = Street;
   }
   public AddressControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
   }

   public string Error
   {
       get
       {
          return null;
       }
   }

   public string this[string name]
   {
      get
      {
          string result = null;

          if (name == "City")
          {
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(City) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City))
              {
                 result = "please enter city";
              }
          }

          if (name == "Street")
          {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Street) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Street))
             {
                 result = "please enter street";
             }
          }
          return result;
      }
   }
}
```

***AddressControl.xaml***

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.AddressControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="600">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CustomTextBoxTextStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="bg" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="Red"/>
                                </Trigger.Setters>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="460"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBlock Text="City :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTextStyle}" TabIndex="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtCity" Padding="10 10 10 3" BorderThickness="2" MinWidth="260" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="City"
                         ValidatesOnExceptions="True"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>

            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Margin="10 10 0 0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                       Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner"
    ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        </TextBox>


        <TextBlock Text="Street :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTextStyle}" TabIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtStreet" Padding="10 10 10 3" BorderThickness="2" MinWidth="260" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Street"
                         ValidatesOnExceptions="True"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>

            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Margin="10 10 0 0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                       Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
    ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

***now Use:You can bind or change the amount of debt immediately***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">       
        <local:AddressControl x:Name="addressControl" City="Paris" Street="Street Menia"></local:AddressControl>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Width="100" Click="btnTest_Click" Margin="0 10 0 0"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

*You can replace the following line*

```
<local:AddressControl x:Name="addressControl" City="Paris" Street="Street Menia"></local:AddressControl>
```

*ٌWith this code*

```
<local:AddressControl x:Name="addressControl" City="{Binding ShippingCity}" Street="{Binding ShippingStreet}"></local:AddressControl>
```

***And Button Click Event in MainWindow***

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string result = "";
   if (Validation.GetHasError(addressControl.txtCity))
   {
       result = Validation.GetErrors(addressControl.txtCity).FirstOrDefault().ErrorContent.ToString();
   }
   MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Comment: I really much appreciate your answer. But the point is that the validation is (and must be) done at the ViewModel, not in the codebehind of the usercontrol itself.

Comment: I know this point and this code corresponds. You do the validation in the viewmodel.

Comment: I can not fully explain because it a simple issue, seems complex . You can add some parameters to the viewmodel and pass them to usercontrol, where if something is found to be invalid, refer it to the control, which is just overtime.

Comment: It all depends on the taste of the programmer